# I am trying to use the google drive api to upload and then download a file so i can implement it in my school project, but it is not uploading

Tags: python, google-drive-api

This is my first time making a "big" prject so I might be going the wrong way about it, but what i am trying to do basically is:
I have a python code that detects faces and i will use it as a smart attendence system in a classroom, the program trains itself with a image set and then creates a file that will be used in the future to consult and detect the faces. It is that file with the trained faces that i am trying to upload.
So, i am using the google drive API to try to upload those files since it is not recomended for large files to be on the database, but when i try to run the code i made to upload files(just a test code to see if it works not the final code) it appears to be succesefull but then in my drive no file appears.

here's the code:

```
`from __future__ import print_function 
import os

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:\\Users\\danie\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\PAP\\teste drive\\iris-face-models-565de449aa27.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

target_folder_id = '1MAM4CPDMbqpzP5rZb1Zw0A15r4U7B4Kv'
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'test_file.txt',
    #'parents': [target_folder_id] if i leave this parents field, which in my understanding would specify which folder in the drive the file would be, it no longer works, which leads me to believe it is not associating to the right drive
}
media = MediaFileUpload('C:\\Users\\danie\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\PAP\\testeicheiro\\Ficheiro_teste.txt', mimetype='text/plain')

file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
`
```

i was expecting the "test_file.txt" to show up in my google drive, my guess is that its either the code or maybe the set up that i did in google cloud that was done wrong

i would love some help, maybe someone more knowledgeable in google api and common mistakes people might make, or just another aproach to my project that i havent thought of, that is maybe more used than google api.

Comment: Make sure that the service account has the correct permissions to access Google Drive and perform file uploads. If the file is supposed to appear in your personal Google Drive, remember that by default, service accounts have their own "Drive" and do not have access to user files unless shared with them or impersonating a user with domain-wide delegation in a G Suite domain. Verify that the `target_folder_id` corresponds to a folder that exists in the drive the service account has access to, and that the service account has permissions to write to this folder.

Comment: If uncommenting the `'parents': [target_folder_id]` line causes the code to fail, verify the folder ID and ensure the service account has write access to that folder. If necessary, try without specifying the parent to see if it uploads to the service account's root drive directory. Also, you can check the response from the Google Drive API call. You are retrieving the `id` of the created file but not printing it. Adding a print statement can help determine whether the API call is successful and can give you an ID that you can use to search for the file.

Comment: Also, verify that the path to the service account credentials file is correct, and the service account JSON file has the right data. Make sure error handling is in place to catch any issues that may arise during the execution of the API request. And again, if the file is uploaded using a service account, the file won't be visible in your personal Google Drive unless shared. Service accounts have their own Drive space.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a service account without parents the file is uploaded to the root folder on the service accounts drive account.

Take the service account email address share a folder on your personal drive account then use that folder id in parents

parents: [target_folder_id]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue with the help of Random Davis, my issue was that i had to share the folder in my drive that i wanted the file to go to with my service account. I had no though of my service account beeing an actual account as silly as it sounds. thanks for the help